# Woocommerce Checkout form validation inside payment plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, hook-woocommerce

I am a beginner in wordpress, and developing custom payment plugin for woocommerce. what I want is before triggering payment processing wanted to validate checkout form as per rules given and validation is fail stop the execution and return the error message.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_validation');

function is_phone() { 
    $some_field = $_POST['your_field_name']; //this is how you get the value of your field.
    if($some_field == "") { //here we check if the field is empty, you can add your rules.
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Your field is empty, please fill it' ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

And at the end we add a notice with the message you want to show, also we note it is an error. This goes into functions.php of your theme. You can edit the message you get and also the rule. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I don't want to add new custom validation I just want to call existing validation before the payment processing call

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'action_function_name_873' );
function action_function_name_873(){
    if(wc_notice_count( 'error' ) == 0 ) 
     {
         wc_add_notice( __( 'Your error message' ), 'error' );
     }

}
```